# How to make video out of frames with a given frame rate?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, photo-management, framerate

I have frames extracted from video with 24 fps (I used ffmpeg), now I need to glue them back with the same frame rate.

Comment: What `ffmpeg` version are you using?

Comment: @dma_k 4.2.4 currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Input and output using same frame rate

Use the `-framerate` input option:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i input_%03d.png output.foo
```

- Default is `-framerate 25`. The output will use the same frame rate as the input.
- This example assumes each input is sequentially named `input_001.png`, `input_002.png`, etc.
- See the [FFmpeg image file demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more details.

## Input and output using different frame rate

If you want to show each image for a certain amount of time, but have a standard output frame rate for compatibility you can add the `-r` output option and frames will be dropped or duplicated to compensate. In the following example each image will be shown for 1 second, but the output will have a frame rate of 24. Without `-r` many players would not be able to play a video with a frame rate of 1.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input_%03d.png -r 24 output.foo
```

Comment: With the command you provided, `mediainfo output.foo` should show 24 fps? In my case it shows 1 fps. I've tried `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i image_%d.png -r 25 -vcodec libx264 out.mkv` and `ffmpeg -r 1 -i image_%d.png -r 25 -vcodec libx264 out.mkv` and those both produce the same MKV with 1 fps (no image duplication). What should be on output if images are duplicated? [Sample of output video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xib95vod2cawxq/demo_shrink_2018-09-24.mkv?dl=0) generated by `ffmpeg` v3.2.10.

Comment: @dma_k For MKV add `-vsync cfr` output option, or replace `-r 25` with `-vf fps=25`, or leave file as is if it works fine.

Comment: Many thanks, `-vf fps=25` has solved the problem.